# Get data of website

Tags: swift, parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'd like to get the data of a website. I'd like to display the table in an app. Do you have an idea how I could do it? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you'd want the maintainer of the data you need to supply some API for machine-to-machine communication (a REST JSON web service, for example).

Since you are asking how to display the table in an app:

- the easiest way would be to just point an `UIWebView` that way and go from there.
- a more native look might be acomplished by parsing the data. As you included several 'parsing' tags, I guess this is what you'd prefer.

The problem with HTML scraping web pages (what you probably hope to do) is that the data you are looking for and foremost it's structure is prune to changes. If some unexpected changes can easily break your parser.

Thus, if you go for doing that (which might be prohibited by your school or other publisher, especially in germany), try to parse the data on your server and offer an web service for your app yourself. This way, you can react to changes of the structure faster and do not break the app for your users.

**Seriously consider asking the school for an API**.

Comment: Ok, I asked my school but the don't have any API. Is there another way to get the data?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, the other options are a web view and creating a parser that supplies data to your own web service.

Comment: Can you give me an example how I could do it?

Comment: Which option? And no; this is not a code writing service and it's not a few lines.

Comment: I'd like to parse the data in a tableView. I just don't really know how to get the data from the website. You really can't give me a small example? Just for downloading the data that I have a beginning.